# Get plugin option in another PHP file

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

I making a plugin, and I registered several options in the plugin PHP file. So let's consider :

```
my-plugin/
   - my-plugin.php (options are registered here)
   - admin.php (the admin page of the plugin)
   - parts/
     conf.php (here I try to get options I registered and used in my plugin)
```

I tried to perform a `get_option()` in the conf.php file, but it doesn't seem to work : it returns empty. The option is registered and set in the DB (I checked).

I guess I can't access to WP registered options from that file ? How can I achieve that ?

EDIT :
I can have a log of the error :

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function get_option() in <b>conf.php</b> on line <b>6</b>
```

Comment: How do you _access_ `conf.php`? Direct request? Is the file `require`d or `include`d?

Comment: I use require_once on a file on the same level. Then this file is loaded in an Ajax way.

Comment: But you are in WordPress context, right? Otherwise you'd need to boostrap WordPress. Do you have Debugging turned on? What does `var_dump( get_option( 'option_name' ) )` tell you?

Comment: See my last edit, I guess I'm not in Wordpress context.

Comment: Use the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) in WordPress.

Comment: I already use Ajax api in this plugin, but that's not the problem here. I just wanna get registered options outside WP context.

Comment: You said in your comment above that you were loading this file via Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

**I finally included the external PHP file in a Wordpress function in my plugin PHP file.**

```
function get_conf_function(){

  require_once(dirname(__FILE__) ."/parts/conf.php"); 

}
```

Now, I can access to wp functions when I call that function (with Ajax or not).